# Firefox AT-SPI support in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, firefox, accessibility

I'm trying to use AT-SPI to get properties of Firefox:

```cpp
auto desktop = atspi_get_desktop(0);
auto count = atspi_accessible_get_child_count(desktop, nullptr);
for (auto ix = 0; ix < count; ix++) {
    auto win = atspi_accessible_get_child_at_index(desktop, ix, nullptr);
    auto name = atspi_accessible_get_name(win, nullptr);
    std::cout << name << std::endl;
}
```

This prints names of all windows, however Firefox is not there.

I installed [Accerciser](https://help.gnome.org/users/accerciser/stable/introduction.html.en) to validate if it works there, it also doesn't show Firefox.

This reproduces on Ubuntu 20.10 and a couple of others. So far I haven't seen Firefox working anywhere, but [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Learn/Accessibility/What_is_accessibility#accessibility_apis), AT-SPI should be supported.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing on 20.04.  Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I found the solution for my system.  Apparently, Firefox on Gnome 3 doesn't obey the normal gconf accessibility setting and instead looks for GNOME_ACCESSIBILITY (1 is enabled).

Answer (score 0):

Firefox application maybe in another desktop.
Try

```
auto desktop = atspi_get_desktop(1);
auto desktop = atspi_get_desktop(2);
```

and etc.

You can also get the count of all desktops:

```
auto cnt = atspi_get_desktop_count();
```

Or maybe Firefox isnt use at-spi2 now. Try it in terminal:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --type=method_call --dest=org.a11y.Bus /org/a11y/bus org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set string:org.a11y.Status string:IsEnabled variant:boolean:true
```